# handle pushwoosh with custom view

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, pushwoosh

i am using pushwoosh library , and i have my own `BroadcastReceiver` to handle push notification .

i have updated the pushwoosh library and now i get my notifiction twice and they even does not look the same .

the reason is that i am handle my push with my class and pushwoose also handle the notification with there class :

public class GCMListenerService extends GcmListenerService {
    private static final String TAG = GCMListenerService.class.getName();

```
public GCMListenerService() {
}

public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    Log.info(TAG, "Received message: " + (data != null?data.toString():"<null>") + " from: " + from);

    try {
        PushServiceHelper.generateNotification(this.getApplicationContext(), data);
    } catch (Exception var4) {
        Log.exception(var4);
    }

}
```

}

how can i prevent from pushwoosh to handle notification ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Factories (extending AbsNotificationFactory ) instead of custom BroadcastReceiver.

Like in the guide here:
http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/android-faq#customizing-push-notifications